# Android populate google calendar attachment field with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar

In my app I am building an intent for the user to create a calendar event with some basic information:

```
fun build(): Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT).apply {
    type = "vnd.android.cursor.item/event"
    putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title)
    putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description)
    putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location)
    putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime)
    putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime)
    putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, true)
}
```

launching this intent prompts the user to select a calendar app to handle this action. For Google calendar there is an "attachment" field that references a google drive link:

[image: calendar attachment]

Is there any way to pass a google drive link for this field from my app to populate it when shown to the user?

(I realize this can be done with the calendar API but want to do it without user authorization)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Add Calendar Event](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#AddEvent) intent documentation, the default data that can be passed to create a calendar event is the following:

- EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY
- EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME
- EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME
- TITLE
- DESCRIPTION
- EVENT_LOCATION
- EXTRA_EMAIL

The documentation also states that

> Many more event details can be specified using the constants defined in the CalendarContract.EventsColumns class.

Since the [CalendarContract.EventsColums](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns#HAS_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES) class docs doesn't expose any field related to attachments, **I would conclude what you are trying to do is not feasible through an intent.**

There might be some workarounds to still make this work (you might as well go as far as de-compiling the calendar app to check what data it really deserializes from intents) but given such workarounds wouldn't benefit from official support I would strongly discourage trying to pursue them, as they might put your app at a risk of breaking in unpredictable ways when any preconditions for such workarounds to work change.